# selectize.js displaying selected value when user clicks back page button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js in a project. I'm using laravel 4.2. When user posts a form and then clicks back button, the form's input values that user write are displaying on the screen. But selectboxes created by using selectize are empty.

How can I display selected values of selectboxes created by using selectize when user clicks back page button on a web browser?

Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: showing us some codes will make your question clearer

Comment: The input values are restored by the browser itself when the user goes back. But Selectize is powered by JavaScript and creates a new input programmatically, so the browser mechanism doesn't work here. If you want to support this, you have to fill the `items` field yourself.